# Installed LAMP stack using taskel and nothing works

Tags: magento, ubuntu, lamp

I never used taskell before but heard it was "so easy" so I used it.

I've never had so much trouble getting a Magento installation to work.

I transferred all the files, db, and everything, but I'm getting errors I can't figure out the source of.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 901`

Maybe this has to do with SPL autoload? But it's enabled in both. I don't know. All I know is it's supposed to just work, like Apple products always just do.

Main difference is this is Ubuntu 12.04.1 (server). Before I've only used Ubuntu 10 and CentOS.
And on Ubuntu 10 I installed the LAMP at the time of OS install. But the server hosts did not do it so I used taskel and now everything sucks.

Using YUM on CentOS was a nightmare, but this is an even bigger one.

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that when I created the `tar.gz` file on the server there were some files I didn't have permission to read, in `app/etc/modules`. All I had to do was transfer those over.

I figured out the answer after I decided to redo the `tar.gz` and saw "permission denied" a bunch of times in the output. I checked the new server and saw that those files were indeed missing.

After transferring them, everything worked immediately.

So, it had nothing to do with taskel or the Ubuntu version. Just some missing files.